# Converting PDF to Excel using Adobe PDF Tool API in .NET

Tags: c#, .net, adobe

I am working on an azure function in which I need to convert PDF to Excel. I am using Adobe PDF Tools API for the conversion. The PDF is in my azure storage account I access it using datalake file client and read the content in memory stream. Then I use the API and the code is shown in the picture.

```
    await file.ReadToAsync(memoryStream);
Credentials credentials = Credentials.ServiceAccountCredentialsBuilder()
                                   .FromFile("pdftools-api-credentials.json")
                                   .Build();

Adobe.DocumentServices.PDFTools.ExecutionContext executionContext = Adobe.DocumentServices.PDFTools.ExecutionContext.Create(credentials);
                        ExportPDFOperation exportPdfOperation = ExportPDFOperation.CreateNew(ExportPDFTargetFormat.XLSX);
                        
FileRef sourceFileRef = FileRef.CreateFromStream(memoryStream, ExportPDFOperation.SupportedSourceFormat.PDF.GetMediaType());
                        exportPdfOperation.SetInput(sourceFileRef);
FileRef result = exportPdfOperation.Execute(executionContext);
```

Now, when I run this , I get the following error:

"Error response received for the request: An error occurred while sending the request. The response ended prematurely."

The code is in C#.

Can someone please help? Thank you in advance

Answer (score 0):

I was getting the same error when exporting a pdf to images.

I downgraded the Adobe.DocumentServices.PDFTools NuGet package from version 1.3.0 to 1.2.0 and it gave me a more useful error message: "The input file is a zero length file."

Adding this fixed it for me.

```
memoryStream.Position = 0;
```